# How to edit build.prop file in Android 11

Tags: file-permissions, android-11, flashlight, build.prop

I have a TCL 20e (6125A) with Android 11. I want to increase the torch brightness. As I read in another post, this can be done by adding these two lines in the file:

```
ro.media.capture.flashintensity=50
ro.media.capture.torchintensity=50
```

I look everywhere and can't root my device, and the two custom recoveries that I find don't work on my phone.

Is it possible to edit this file without custom recovery? Any other chance?

Comment: You don't need a custom recovery but you need a rooted device, because `build.prop` file is read-only by default and for writing it you need root.

Answer (score 0):

1. Factory reset and install Magisk app 24.3
2. Patch your firmware’s boot and nulled vbmeta by Magisk app
3. Install TWRP app and wait for your TWRP images on XDA ...
4. Flash your device’s TWRP by any PC tools
5. Flash Magisk patched boot and vbmeta by TWRP
6. Flash your GSI, and you’ve been rooted (VNDK GSI ROM’s are rw, others are ro)
7. Patch your vbmeta and boot once more to root on GSI again
8. Edit sth you need to edit by root apps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).